# Why my reverse proxy (nginx) does not work

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am installing a site under my machine. I have a NodeJS server that listens on **port 4000.**
I am using an NGINX reverse proxy, so that it is accessible from **port 80**. Here is the following configuration in / sites-availabes

```
upstream site {
  server 127.0.0.1:4000;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name site.infra.monsite.blog;
   
   location / {
       proxy_pass http://site;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
}
```

But I can't access my site from **site.infra.monsite.blog;** which points to port 80 of the machine.
Are there any ports to open like on Windows, or an NGINX configuration that I missed?

Yet when I do "curl -X GET http://localhost/": It works on the machine.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: yes, port 80 http should be open in your firewall and domain should point to the machine

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
upstream site {
  server 127.0.0.1:4000;
  keepalive 64;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}


location / {
    proxy_pass http://site;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass_header  Set-Cookie;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass_header X-XSRF-TOKEN;
    proxy_read_timeout 240s;
   }
```